# Spring AMQP - Is there a method that's responsible for routing to the listeners

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

If I want to debug why my listeners (annotated with `@RabbitListener`) aren’t being triggered, what’s a class in `spring.amqp.rabbit` I should place a breakpoint on for debugging the issue? In other words, is there a method that's responsible for routing to the listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is one: `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener()`.

But you really should be sure that you haven't missed to add `@EnableRabbit` and there is really some messages in the queue to listen.